# Remove specific cell border in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

> The `<colgroup>` tag is useful for applying styles to entire columns, instead of repeating the styles for each cell, for each row.

I applied `colgroup` to my table by adding

```
<colgroup>
  <col span="6" style="border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7">
</colgroup>
```

below `<table>` tag. 
So now all the cells have right border in all rows
but I need to delete border in specific cell. 
How can I do that ?

```css
    .details-map:before{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 70px;
    }
    .details-map:after{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .noborder{
     border-right: 1px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .noborderall{
     border-right: 1px solid transparent;
     border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .noborderr{
     border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    }
```

```html
               <table class="table">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col span="6" style="border-right: 2px solid red">
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th width="5.4%">Rank</th>
                            <th width="27.3%">School</th>
                            <th width="12.5%">Student to Faculty Ratio</th>
                            <th width="12.5%">Acceptance Rate</th>
                            <th width="11.3%">Graduation Rate</th>
                            <th width="12.3%">Median Debt Incurred</th>
                            <th width="31.2%">Median Earnings/Total Expense</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">1</th>
                              <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
                              <td>XX/1</td>
                              <td>XX%</td>
                              <td>XX%</td>
                              <td>$XX,XXX</td>
                              <td>$XX,XXX/$XX,XXX</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">2</th>
                              <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
                              <td>XX/1</td>
                              <td>XX%</td>
                              <td>XX%</td>
                              <td>$XX,XXX</td>
                              <td>$XX,XXX/$XX,XXX</td>
                            </tr>
                      </tbody>
                         <tbody class="details-map">
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row" class="noborder">&nbsp;</th>
                              <th scope="row" >Lorem Ipsum Dolor</th>
                              <th scope="row" class="noborderall">&nbsp;</th>
                              <th scope="row" class="noborderr">&nbsp;</th>
                              <td colspan="3" rowspan="7">
                                  <button class="buttons">School website</button>
                                  <button class="buttons">Financial Aid Office</button>
                                  <button class="buttons">Prospecitve students</button>
                                  <div id="googleMap"></div>
                                  
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" >Expense Ratio</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderall">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderr right-align">XX/10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" >Acceptance Rate Score</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderall">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderr right-align">XX/10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="left-align">Graduation Rate Score</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderall">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderr right-align">XX/10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="left-align">ROI/Value</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderall">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderr right-align">XX/10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" >Student to Faculty Ratio</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderall">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td scope="row" class="noborderr right-align">XX/10</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td colspan="4" scope="row" class="noborderr" >
                              <h2>About the scores</h2>
                              <p>
                                  Using a complex algorithm our review tool examines all of the schools in Pennsylvania that offer Computer Science Majors and provides a score for several categories.
                              </p>
                             </td>
                            </tr>  
                      </tbody>
                           <tbody>
                            
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">3</th>
                              <td>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
                              <td>XX/1</td>
                              <td>XX%</td>
                              <td>XX%</td>
                              <td>$XX,XXX</td>
                              <td>$XX,XXX/$XX,XXX</td>
                            </tr>
                         
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Padding doesn't work in `tbody` so I used before and after pseudo elements to add space. In this space I need to delete the border.

Comment: Can you add entire html code?

Comment: Do you know which is that specific cell? If yes, add the styles. If not, tell us your HTML and mark the specific cell to stylish with CSS

Comment: you have errors in syntax: you used tbody inside tbody that's not allowed, please make correction and update question too

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili done

Comment: Is there a reason this is all in one table? This would be *so much easier* for you if you just used a few separate tables and a `<div>` or two.

Answer (score 1):

you can give an **id** or **class** to your choice of col (which should not have border) and add the **border:none** property to it

HTML :

```
<colgroup>
  <col span="6" style="border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7">
<col span="6" style="border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7">
<col span="6" style="border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7">
<col span="6" class="tb" style="border-right: 1px solid #b7b7b7">
</colgroup>
```

CSS :

```
.tb{
 border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo for remove specific cell border.
[Demo Table Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jitendrathakur/53qa77ex/)

**CSS**

```css
tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(2) {
  border-right: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using before and after so I don't know how to specify the cell. copy my code and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: same nth-child apply with before and after after that you will remove specific cell border